# How to show that the sum of N indep & identical real random variables lies in a fixed finite interval with probability going to zero as N increases?

Tags: probability, random-variables

With the central limit theorem, it is easy to show that the sum S_N  of N independent and identical real-valued random variables X_1,X_2,... with finite means and variances lies in any given finite interval I with probability going to zero. But this is such a simple basic fact that it ought to be learned and proved before the central limit theorem. One could think of this as the "law of spreading".

Any ideas?

One potential approach is to let K = (-k, k), where k is chosen large enough that K contains I. Then using Chebychev's inequality

Pr(S_N \in I) ≤ Pr(S_N \in K) = Pr(|S_N| ≤ k) = Pr( g(|S_N|) ≥ g(k) )

```
          ≤  E [ (g(|S_N|))^2 ] /  k^2
```

where g is a monotonic function such that E[(|g(S_N)|)^2] / k^2 goes to 0 as N goes to infinity for every distribution of the X_i's.

Is there such a function g?

Clearly Markov's inequality could be used instead of Chebychev's.  Chernoff's, too, but the latter requires more explanation.

Or perhaps there's an entirely different approach.